# Комментирование куска текста в vim

Tags: vim

Есть любой кусок текста, хотелось бы его полностью закомментировать за пару действий вне зависимости от его размера.

Answer (score 5):

Плагином пользоваться не хотелось бы по той простой причине - что нужна универсальность) Частенько приходится работать с разных машин, в том числе и чужих - поэтому только чистый `vim`)

Для себя нарыл сейчас такой вариант:
`ctr+v` дальше `}` - до конца абзаца либо `j,k` выделение. Дальше `I` , `#` и `<ESC>`

Answer (score 3):

Я для этого пользуюсь плагином [tComment](https://github.com/vim-scripts/tComment). С ним можно выделить текст, нажать комбинацию клавиш  (горячие клавиши настраиваются), и нужные строки будут закомментарены. Раскомментаривание происходит так же. Плюс есть ещ несколько полезных горячих клавиш.

Answer (score 2):

Можно использовать [The NERD Commenter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1218) или [аналоги](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1173). Комментирование в нажатие двух-трех кнопок. Предварительно они требуют выделить текст, а это уже отдельное действие и в некоторых случаях может быть выполненно и за одно-два нажатия.

Answer (score 2):

Этот ответ годится только для однострочных комментариев, но тем не менее.
Для комментирования C++-кода можно так сделать:

^**Ctrl+v**5jI//

где **^** - **Shift+6**, **5** - количество строк вниз, **I** - **Shift+i**.
Возможны любые перемещения вместо **5j**, например, **}**.

Для другого языка можно заменить `//` на соответствующий символ комментария (`#`, `--` и т.п.)

Upd: Спасибо @Dofri и @KoVadim за замечания. Dofri более прав оказался относительно **Ctrl+v**.

Comment: да, вы меня опередили буквально на минуту) для блоковых комментов я написал ниже)

Comment: только имейте ввиду, что не во всех языках код комментируется с помощью двух слешей. Ещё очень популярно комментировать решеткой:)

Answer (score 1):

Для комментирования блока я всегда использовал режим визуального выделения, который вызывается по

> ctrl+v

(в gvim для windows по умолчанию ctrl+q).

Нужно поставить курсор, например, в начале строки наверху выделяемого блока, нажать

> ctrl+v

, переместить курсор в конец параграфа, нажав

> }

, затем нажать

> I (shift+i)

, ввести символ комментария (например, #) и нажать ESC.

детальнее:

https://lisakov.com/blog/vim-comment-block/

Comment: вроде должны результаты проверки ответов а их нету...

Comment: а что тут проверять? вы просто перепечатали прошлый ответ :)

Answer (score 0):

У меня было желание не просто **быстро** комментировать/раскомментировать кусок текста, но чтобы еще и символ комментария автоматически выбирался верный.
И из любопытства я написал плагин, которым вот уж пару лет как пользуюсь и сильно привык, надо сказать )

Работает оно так: выделяю кусок текста и нажимаю `hh`. Если выделить закомментированный кусок и нажать `hh`, то кусок раскомментируется.

.vimrc:

```
nmap hh :LinesCommentNextState <CR>
vmap hh :LinesCommentNextState <CR>
```

код плагина:

```
function! s:LinesCommentNextState() range

    let l:extension = expand('%:e')

    let l:comment_symbol = "#"
    if l:extension == "c"
        let l:comment_symbol = "\/\/"
    elseif l:extension == "cpp"
        let l:comment_symbol = "\/\/"
    elseif l:extension == "h"
        let l:comment_symbol = "\/\/"
    elseif l:extension == "hpp"
        let l:comment_symbol = "\/\/"
    elseif l:extension == "xs"
        let l:comment_symbol = "\/\/"
    elseif l:extension == "vim"
        let l:comment_symbol = "\""
    elseif l:extension == "lua"
        let l:comment_symbol = "--"
    else
        "default '#'
    endif

    let l:first_line = getline(a:firstline)

    let l:need_comment = 1

    " if string already commented, no need comment twice
    if l:first_line =~ '\v^(\s)*' . l:comment_symbol
        let l:need_comment = 0
    endif

    for n in range (a:firstline, a:lastline)
        let l:line = getline (n)

        if len(l:line) == 0
            continue
        endif

        if l:need_comment == 1
            " comment it!
            let l:new_line = l:comment_symbol . l:line

            " but if beginning from space, need save all spaces
            if l:line =~ '\v^\s'
                let l:matches = matchlist(l:line, '\v^(\s+)(.*)')
                let l:new_line = l:matches[1] . l:comment_symbol . l:matches[2]
            endif
        else
            let l:new_line = l:line

            if l:line =~ '\v^(\s*)' . l:comment_symbol
                let l:matches = matchlist(l:line, '\v^(\s*)' . l:comment_symbol . '(.*)')
                let l:new_line = l:matches[1] . l:matches[2]
            endif
        endif

        call setline (n, l:new_line)
    endfor
endfunction

function! SaveCursor()
    let s:cursor = getpos('.')
endfunction

function! RestoreCursor()
    call setpos('.', s:cursor)
    unlet s:cursor
endfunction

command! -range LinesCommentNextState call SaveCursor() | <line1>,<line2>call s:LinesCommentNextState() | call RestoreCursor()
```